# $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p$ and $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ - quotients by ideals of points in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-space, blowup

**Question:**

Consider $X\equiv\mathbb{P}^2$ (the complex projective space), and a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$. Let $\mathfrak{m}_p$ be the maximal ideal of $p$.

**Is it the case that $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p$ and $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ are both sheaves supported only at $p$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$ respectively? How should one think about this in terms of functions on the patches of $\mathbb{P}^2$?**

What I would like to understand is how to think about these as sheaves, and how to see from the definition of sheaves and quotient sheaves that this is their behaviour, in particular in terms of functions on the usual coordinate patches on $\mathbb{P}^2$. I am used to thinking about line bundles, and their transition functions, and I usually use $\mathbb{P}^1$ as a simple example in which to illustrate ideas, but I am not used to thinking about sheaves like this. It would be nice to be able to think clearly about these quotients on $\mathbb{P}^1$ first.

---

**Context and thoughts:**

In Lemma 1 of Chapter 3 of Friedman's *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundles*, Friedman considers a blow-up $\rho:\tilde{X}\to X$ of a surface $X$ at the point $p\in X$, with the exceptional divisor $E=\rho^{-1}(p)\cong\mathbb{P}^1$. The following theorem is then stated.

**Lemma 1:** *Let $\mathfrak{m}_p$ be the maximal ideal of $p$ in $X$. Then*
$$
\rho_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(aE)=
\begin{cases}
\mathfrak{m}_p^n,~~\textit{if }a=-n<0, \\
\mathcal{O}_X,~~\textit{if }a\geq0.
\end{cases}
$$

Now consider the short exact sequence,
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E) \to \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}} \to \mathcal{O}_E \to 0 \,.
\tag{1}
\label{1}
$$
After tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E)$ we get,
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-2E) \to \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E) \to \mathcal{O}_E(1) \to 0 \,,
\tag{2}
\label{2}
$$
where we have noted that $E^2=-1$, so that $\mathcal{O}_E\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E)=\mathcal{O}_E(1)\cong\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$.

Now, it can also be shown that $R^i\rho_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(aE)=0$ for $i>0$ when $a\leq0$ - this is stated for example [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1991-04-03/S0894-0347-1991-1092845-5/S0894-0347-1991-1092845-5.pdf) at the bottom of page 592. So now consider the long exact sequences of pushforwards and higher direct images associated with the short exact sequences \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} above. Since $R^1\rho_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}=R^1\rho_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E)=0$, in both cases we get a short exact sequence involving just the pushforwards. Making use of the above lemma, these can be written respectively as follows,
$$
0 \to \mathfrak{m}_p \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \rho_*\mathcal{O}_E \to 0 \,,
\tag{3}
\label{3}
$$
$$
0 \to \mathfrak{m}_p^2 \to \mathfrak{m}_p \to \rho_*\mathcal{O}_E(1) \to 0 \,.
\tag{4}
\label{4}
$$
Hence we can identify,
$$
\rho_*\mathcal{O}_E\cong\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p ~~\text{and}~~
\rho_*\mathcal{O}_E(1)\cong\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2\,.
$$
Now, the blow-down $\rho$ acts on the $\mathbb{P}^1$ as a map from the whole space to a point, and the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_E(n)$ effectively lives only on the $\mathbb{P}^1$. By the definition of the pushforward $f_*\mathcal{F}$ as the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto H^0(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F}_{f^{-1}(U)})$ (for a map $f$ of topological spaces), since in the map of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to a point the inverse image of the point is just the whole $\mathbb{P}^1$, we expect that $\rho_*\mathcal{O}_E(n)$ will be a sheaf supported only at $p$ and isomorphic to $H^0(\mathcal{O}_E(n))\cong\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ (using $\binom{n+1}{n}=n+1$) for $n\geq0$ (and isomorphic to $0$ otherwise).

Hence in our particular case, we expect $\rho_*\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\rho_*\mathcal{O}_E(1)$ to be supported only at $p$ and to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$ respectively. So recalling \eqref{3} and \eqref{4}, we see that this must be true of $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p$ and $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$, respectively. Since I know that $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p\cong i_*\mathcal{O}_P$ by a general result (with $i:p\to X$ the inclusion map), and since clearly $i_*\mathcal{O}_P\cong\mathbb{C}$, the first of these results is at least clearly correct, though I do not have a good 'feel' for this by thinking about the quotient sheaf.

Answer (score 1):

This is a local question. Take a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^2$, projective plane has a standard covering by 3 affine open sets, point $p$ is in one of these sets $p \in \mathbb{A}^2$. There rest is commutative algebra.

Let $m$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{A}^2 = \text{Spec} k[x_1,x_2]$ corresponding to $p$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,p} \cong k[x_1,x_2]_m$, and $m_p$ is the maximal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. The residue field  $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/m_p \cong k(p)$ is isomorphic to $k$ if $k$ is algebraically closed. The quotient $m_p/m_p^2$ is by definition a conormal bundle of ${p}$, which is in the case of a closed point is just the fiber of cotangent bundle at the point, indeed $\dim m_p/m_p^2 =\dim \mathbb{P}^2=2$.

These are local question, it is enough to work in one affine chart and no need to work with transition functions etc

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your answer. Currently I don't understand it exactly, as my algebraic geometry is poor, but I will try to figure it out. 

I understand I should be able to work locally, but I think it is taking into account other regions that leads to my confusion, so while I try to understand this answer, I will in the meantime explain how I am lead to the wrong conclusion.

Take $\mathbb{P}^1$ with homogeneous coordinates $y_0$ and $y_1$, and take a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^1$ at $y_0=0$.

I think of $\mathfrak{m}_p$ as consisting of regular functions vanishing at $p$.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ just consists of constant functions, $\mathfrak{m}_p$ just contains the zero function.

If I consider $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$, then on $y_0\neq0$, I would assign the regular function $c\cdot\tfrac{y_1}{y_0}$ (an order-one zero, dropping order-two etc). In this patch, this means I have a single complex parameter. However if I want to match this with a regular function on $y_1\neq0$, it seems I must set $c=0$ (or get a pole at $y_1=0$). I also can't see how there is localisation of the sheaf at a point.

Comment: Well, perhaps I should think about this as follows. My previous comment was really an argument for there being no non-trivial global sections, since I can't patch things together consistently. Thinking of what the pre-sheaf assigns to the patches on $\mathbb{P}^1$, on $y_1\neq0\equiv V$, $\mathfrak{m}_p(V)/\mathfrak{m}_p^2(V)$ is empty, so I can only assign the zero function to $V$. Only on $y_0\neq0$ can I assign something non-trivial, so this is how the sheaf gets localised at $p$.

Comment: Ideal $m_p$ is the maximal in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. Informally ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is the ring of regular functions defined in a small neighborhood of $p$, functions vanishing at this point form ideal $m_p$.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I think I understand your answer now. But I have the following question. Let $\mathscr{I}_p$ be the sheaf of ideals of the point $p$, as defined on p.68/69 of Hartshorne. Is $\mathfrak{m}_p\cong\mathscr{I}_p$? If not, how can I understand $\mathfrak{m}_p$ as a sheaf? Additionally, I see that $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ is just a fibre at $p$, as is $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathfrak{m}_p$, but is $\mathfrak{m}_p$ also just a fibre at $p$?

Comment: (Also, sorry, in my above comments, the first comment should have put $p$ at $y_1=0$ not at $y_0=0$, and in the second comment, 'or get a pole at $y_1=0$' should read 'or get a pole at $y_0=0$'.)

Comment: You understand sheaf $\mathscr{I}_p$ by computing it on affine open sets i.e. $\mathscr{I}_p(U)$ is $0$ if $p$ not in $U$ and ideal of $p$ if $p \in U$. This is NOT the same as $m_p$. The $\mathscr{I}_p$ is the sheaf of ideals, but $m_p$ is an ideal in local ring.

Comment: In my question, under `context and thoughts', I quoted a lemma by Friedman. Given what we've said, it seems this lemma must be technically incorrect. For one, $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is not a sheaf, and the pushforward should be a sheaf. Second, I've seen the same result stated elsewhere but with $\mathscr{I}_p$ instead of $\mathfrak{m}_p$. I think my confusion stems from thinking $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is equal to $\mathscr{I}_p$, and partly this came from seeing this lemma stated correctly elsewhere but, it seems, technically incorrectly here by Friedman.